Using JTAG to access memory by writing/reading to DR/IR registers with target ARM processor and master FTDI 4ch chip
So generally I want to implement certain memory writing/reading to an ARM processor by using JTAG. Other communication types / hardware are not available.
I control the FTDI chip (MPSSE) from the PC using python and I have already implemented reading IDCODE by

writing IDCODE + BYPASS to IR
reading DR for the IDCODE

So I can confirm that my methods for reading DR, writing IR works.
Based on some of the tutorials I have found out that a good start is reading the CTRL/STATUS register by DPACC, but I have some problems doing that.
I'm not sure if it's okay but after writing APACC or DPACC to IR, I can read out 00000010 and even if I write something to DR (35 bits of data after DPACC/APACC), reading out the DR always gives out the same 00000010 (ARM docs on the ACK)
Where am I going wrong? Any ideas? Maybe I need to enable the systemdebugpwr or any other powers on the CTRL/STATUS register but I can't really know that I have enabled that without being able to confirm that my write_DR() method works
I have spent numerous hours on this and any link to a guide I haven't read or any guidance would be a big help. I don't really have any experience with embedded programming and chips/processors so I don't know most of the keywords/things
I have tried writing random 35 bit data after IR APACC/DPACC command and then check if any time the data from DR would change but it never did.
I have NOT tried different hardwares (so maybe the target ARM (cortex m3) is fault?).
I have tried changing the order I shift the data in (lsb/msb) - nothing really happens.
I have tried writing to CTRL/STATUS to enable the power to the debug - no idea if it works or not.
I have tried collecting the data through a logic tool that captures and parses (analyzes) the pin movements up and down and confirms most of the logic for JTAG is ok. I could attach it somehow
